Using Phrase.com (translation service) with Xcode String Catalogs?
We're using Phrase.com for translating our strings. Unfortunately they do not support String Catalogs yet. I'm looking for a way to use String Catalogs and still be able to work with Phrase.
I found that Apple is converting the String Catalogs internally to classic strings files to keep the app compatible with older systems:

String Catalogs are designed specifically for interaction within an Xcode project. As JSON files under the hood, they should also be easily diffable in source control. Then, at build time, these files compile to .strings and .stringsdict files. Because these file formats have been supported in our operating systems for many years now, I'm happy to say that you can start using String Catalogs right away without having to update your minimum deployment target

Taken from: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10155?time=1679
If i can find a way to access these generated strings files, i would be able to upload them to Phrase. (Download and import should be less of a problem because Xcode can import and convert.)
Has someone a hint how i can get these generated strings files?
